# Accessing Child Controls Through Variable

Tags: vba

The code that follows is a simplified version of what I am trying to do, contained within a module and I have `Set InputSheet = Sheets("Input")` in `Public Sub Workbook_Open()` of `ThisWorkbook`:

```
Option Explicit

Public InputSheet As Worksheet

Public Sub Populate()

    InputSheet.ListBox2.AddItem "Test" 'doesnt work
    Sheets("Input").ListBox2.AddItem "Test2" 'works

End Sub
```

As indicated by the comments, the first line within `Populate()` doesn't work, the second line works fine. The error I am getting with the first line is `Method or data member not found`. Can someone point me in the right direction? It doesn't seem to be anything to do with the fact that I am using a global variable because if I do:

```
Dim InputSheet2 As Worksheet
Set InputSheet2 = Sheets("Input")

InputSheet2.ListBox2.AddItem "Test"
```

It has the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that it happens the way you say it does. Also, I don't know why it happens that way, but I can guess. When you use `Sheets("Input")`, the library is starting with a generic Sheet class before it ends up in the more specific Worksheet class. But for `InputSheet`, you already in the Worksheet class (you went through Sheet when you set the variable, but not now).

So my guess is there is a bug/feature where the ListBox autoinstantiating property is only part of the Sheet class and not of the Worksheet class. ActiveX controls live on a layer above worksheets so there is plumbing that connects sheets to ActiveX controls, but they're not as tightly bound as they appear in the UI.

You have a couple of options, none of which is what you want. The first, of course, is to use your second line.  Otherwise you could use

```
Public InputSheet As Object
```

That will force VBA to evaluate the object types and go through the Sheet class. Or you could do this.

```
InputSheet.OLEObjects("ListBox2").Object.AddItem "Test3"
```

The best way, in my opinion, is to change the sheet's CodeName and use that - the autoinstantiating properties will work with that. But I realize you've simplified this and that may not work for you.

Comment: Many thanks, I changed the Name property for the sheet so I could just refer to that in place of Sheets("SheetName"). I knew it had to be something simple but I am new to VBA.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, InputSheet has not been initialized and is set to *Nothing*. Before your InputSheet...AddItem "Test", include:

```
Set InputSheet = Sheets("Input")
```

This also assumes you have a sheet named "Input" and the "Input" sheet has a List Box named "ListBox2"

Edit:
Not sure why Excel VBA works this way, but it doesn't look like you can reference child objects in that way. I was able to make it work by using InputSheet.OLEObjects... To make it cleaner, I assigned that to a ListBox object:

```
Public InputSheet As Worksheet

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set InputSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
End Sub

Public Sub Test()
    Dim MyBox As ListBox
    Set ListBox = InputSheet.OLEObjects("ListBox2").Object

    ListBox.AddItem Now()
End Sub
```

I did experience a bit of flakiness with the global variable though. Seemed when I hit errors the InputSheet object would be rest back to *Nothing* and I'd have to close/reopen the workbook to get that value reassigned.

Comment: Please read my whole question again, I said that I am initializing InputSheet in `Public Sub Workbook_Open()` and in my second code block I am doing exactly what you suggested (declaring, setting and using another variable) as a test, which also doesn't work.

Comment: My apologies. I missed that statement.